# Can you tansfer the journal files between instances of HornetQ?

Tags: hornetq

Can the journal files from one instance of HornetQ be copied to and read by another instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as long as you copy bindings / journals and jms altogether.

There are references to queueIDs from message journal that are held into bindings journal.

JMS journal is not that important on this sense but I would keep it as well.

I wouldn't do the copy while the journals are being written as you may get files out of sequence. a Journal is a sequential log and doing these operations on the middle may take you to undesirable results.

You're safe to do it when the journal is not being written (either server idle or stopped).